# "No such file or directory" for existing files in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: scheme, racket

I am getting a weird error of non-existent file in the Amazon EC2 instance, when logged in over ssh.

basically i have installed racket(mzscheme) from [here](http://racket-lang.org/), and it ran the install script perfectly, but after installation when i try to run the created binaries existing in "/home/ubuntu/racket/bin" then it says:

```
-bash: ./mzscheme: No such file or directory
```

basically for any binaries that i am trying to execute.
all the binaries have execute permission for all.

Tried rebooting the instance, with no fix.

```
$ which mzscheme
```

gives

```
/usr/local/bin/mzscheme
```

Thanks for helping.

**EDIT**

Here is a link i found, which talks about the same problem, but no solution, 
[on arc forums](http://arclanguage.org/item?id=9468)

Comment: Can you run racket as in ./racket   ?

Comment: no same error, its weird that i can see the file right there and it still says "No such file or directory"

Comment: Try running `ldd /usr/local/bin/mzscheme`, and see if you have any missing dependencies.

Comment: It Says **not a dynamic executable**

Comment: What dot 
    `less /usr/local/bin/mzscheme`  show?

Comment: Also, what does `chmod /usr/local/bin/mzscheme` say?

Comment: @vinit `mzscheme` _is_ a dynamic executable. If it says that message, it probably means your EC2 instance is 32-bit and you're trying to run a 64-bit Racket. Try downloading a 32-bit version and try again.

Comment: @soegaard the file is there, it says:
`"/usr/local/bin/mzscheme" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?`
and upon yes, it tries to show the binary file on the terminal.

I think you meant:
`ls -l /usr/local/bin/mzscheme`
it says:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 May  2 07:39 /usr/local/bin/mzscheme -> /home/ubuntu/racket/bin/mzscheme`

`ls -l /home/ubuntu/racket/bin/mzscheme`
says
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19573 Feb 18 17:29 /home/ubuntu/racket/bin/mzscheme`

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That was the problem, only difference was: I was running 64-bit machine and racket was 32-bit. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the release mismatch. The Amazon EC2 instance was a 64-bit machine and i installed a 32-bit racket. As @ChrisJester-Young explained in the comments, `mzscheme` being a dynamic executable spits this rather confusing error message.